# Difference between "across" and "through"

Tags: prepositions

> - walk across the tunnel
> - walk through the tunnel

Which one is correct? Can anyone explain me the exact difference between the through and across? I am really confused with these 2 prepositions.

Answer (score 13):

"Walk through the tunnel" means to enter the tunnel on one end and emerge out the other end.

"Walk across the tunnel" *could* mean the same thing, but only if the context establishes that. It could also mean to enter the tunnel through a side entrance, and exit out another side entrance (i.e. the short way, not the long way); or it could mean to go across the *top* of the tunnel (e.g. if it's underground and the road goes over it); or variations on those themes.

In general, "through" implies entering the middle of something and then going out the other side, whereas "across" implies crossing the middle, but not necessarily going *in* the thing you're crossing.

Comment: I have heard "across the USA" and "across the globe". Now, how will you explain them? I walk across the street OR I walk through the street. Which one is correct according to you?

Comment: @hellodear2, if it's long enough, you can walk *through* the grass (because it's brushing against your legs as you go), but it'd be kind of hard to walk *through* the street, don't you think? And what is it about "across the globe" that you feel needs explaining?

Comment: -1 We do not use *Walk across the tunnel* in AmE to mean enter one end, walk the tunnel's length, and emerge from the other end.

Comment: @Martha As you say, you can walk *through* an area by entering the middle of that area then going out the other side. "We made a shortcut through the grass" can mean "We went across this grassy area". The grass need not be long.

Comment: @Era: I dunno. To me, "through the grass" implies at least some grass brushing against your legs; otherwise, "through" is the wrong preposition. Oddly, though, I'm fine with a "shortcut through the field".

Comment: @Martha it's definitely not clear cut. This is a situation in which misunderstanding might occur. I would rephrase or add more context if communicating that distinction is important.

Comment: +1 I agree with all of this. I also disagree that *across* cannot be used to go from one of a tunnel to another; it's not commonly used that way, but it's easily understood.

Answer (score 6):

*Across* is used with surfaces, places, flat objects/areas, or things that you are "on."

*Across* is also used if it's important to mean "on the other side of", or "moving over" something like a river, hole, bridge, etc.

*Through X* is used if you are surrounded by or "in"/"inside" X.

So you go *through* a tunnel, but not *across* it.  If you say you went across a tunnel, it would mean you somehow went over and on top of the tunnel (likely perpendicular to it) and avoided going in it.

You might go through a tunnel to get across a mountain range, though.

Answer (score 3):

Both of these words are used to indicate a movement from one place to another.

Using "**across**" is somehow like using **on**. We usually use **across** to talk about moving from one side to the other, usually on the surface. It is used for a two-dimensional and open space (across a wall, city, sheet of paper, road and ...).

> 1. We took a boat **across** the river.
> 2. Looking out **across** the ocean, he saw land.

Using "**through**", however, is somehow like using **in** or **inside**. Imagine a place which is surrounded by something (for example a tunnel or a forest which is covered with tall trees). When we want to move from one side of this **surrounded** place to the other, we use "through". **Through** is used for a movement in a three-dimensional and covered place.

> 1. I am driving **through** the tunnel.
> 2. She loves walking **through** the forest.

About grass and lawn, if we are talking about a place which is covered with tall or long grass, we should use "through":
[image: long grass]

> When my dog runs **through** long grass, it’s difficult to find him.

but if we are talking about a field covered with short or small grass or lawn, we should use "across":
[image: lawn]

> Tomorrow at this time you'll be chasing peacocks **across** the lawn.

Comment: *In* works with both 2D and 3D shapes - so you can be *in* both a flat square and a cube.  If a strong focus is on those 2D boundaries you might still use *through* to describe moving through a flat space.  For example: "He is trespassing through my lawn."

Answer (score 1):

If it's something *enclosed*, such as a tunnel or passageway, you would usually be said to walk (or pass, or drive) *through* it from end to end. If it's something more or less *open* (but still distinctly separate from the surroundings), such as a bridge, you would usually be said to walk (or pass, or drive) *across* it (and the act is *crossing* it). Something like an ordinary ground-level road or sidewalk you would walk (etc.) *along* or *alongside*.

If you are not moving from one end of this thing (e.g., road) to another, but only briefly occupying the same space, you would usually be *crossing* the road. To *cross* a tunnel would usually mean that it's buried and you're above it, not *within* it at any time, although it would be possible to *cross* a tunnel from another, intersecting tunnel.

Answer (score 1):

To move **through** something, one must be able to be **inside** it either **literally** or **figuratively**.  Usually a **container** or the notion of a container is invoked.

> Walk **through** the tunnel
>   Drive **through** a rain storm
>   Run **through** the forest
>   Walk **through** the streets of London

in each case a **container** is established: **tunnel**, **rain storm**, **forest**, the collection of **London streets**

**Across** usually implies a **position** of being **over** or **on top of** but may mean **close by**, and may, but not necessarily refer to **movement**.

**Referring to movement**

> Walk **across** a bridge
>   Fly **across** the country
>   Run **across** the street

**Referring to over**

> The bridge goes **across** the river
>   Hands **Across** America

**Referring to close by**

> Sit **across** from somebody
>   The building **across** from the station

From your examples, one walks **through** a tunnel is correct

> walk **through** the tunnel **across** to the other side

Comment: Excellent! However, after such a concise explanation, I'm wondering how does "going through the motions" and "going through the plan" fit into all this? There seems to be implied movement by the use of "going" along with an element of repetition or rehearsal, but I can't quite put my finger on the exact explanation. Oh and just a thought: in the cases where across and through are theoretically equivalent (across the field, through the field) I tend to find that the "through" variant implies greater difficulty; some kind of impediment or hardship.

Answer (score 0):

Through is used to cross a three-dimensional place or enclosed object: like a tunnel, forest or jungle.

A forest is a three-dimensional place as it is covered with full of tall trees. In contrast, an open field is usually empty, does not cover with trees, which is act like a two-dimensional place.

> 1. The man is walking across the field.
> 2. The man is walking through the jungle.

[image]

[Credit goes to this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ccPgadJ9Gc)

Answer (score -2):

[image]

across

[image]

through

[image]

across a river and through a bridge.

Comment: We don't walk "through" a bridge - we walk across it, over it, or under it.

Comment: Though a bridge? Though!!? What do you mean?

Comment: "**Over** the river and **through** the woods to Grandmother's house we go."